# Connman Force DHCP Renew

Tags: networking, dhcp

What is the suggested way to force DHCP renewal when using connman?

Is `systemctl restart connman` the right way of doing it or is there any other approach?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

According to the post
[Release and renew DHCP with connman from console](https://discourse.osmc.tv/t/release-and-renew-dhcp-with-connman-from-console/79812),
the command `sudo systemctl restart connman` seems to work but doesn't
really.

The standard way to renew an IP address for the eth0 interface is to release
first the current address:

```
$ sudo dhclient -r eth0
$ sudo dhclient eth0
```

In the above link, an alternative suggestion was made:

```
connmanctl disable ethernet
sleep 10
connmanctl enable ethernet
```

Comment: Thanks @harrymc, in the specific setup that I'm working on we don't have `dhclient`. For the alternative solution of disabling and enabling Ethernet, what's the reason for adding 10 seconds sleep? Would e.g. 1 second be also okay?

Comment: Also just to add, it seems really difficult to find "official" documentation on how exactly to do this (renew DHCP with connman). Anyone has any idea why?

Comment: Seems like this problem is rare. The 10 seconds are probably to let the DHCP server process the request. This might be an overkill, but testing will show that.